# After trying to install nvidia drivers ubuntu boots to a black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

Ubuntu version:19.10 64 bit (dual boot with windows 10)
I tried installing nvidia drivers for my geforce 940 mx, i edited etc/default/grub with nomodeset but now when i turn on my pc it shows Ubuntu loading screen and then it loads a black screen with an underscore on the top left corner. From there i can use ctr+alt+f3 to get to the console but i don't know what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install the drivers? Is this boot with `nomodeset` or without? Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: I followed this video : https://youtu.be/GljujCLixzE (i downloaded the drivers from nvdia site) and secure boot is disabled. How do i check if the boot is with nomodeset?

Comment: You cannot use nomodeset once drivers are installed. (ultimately using the upstream driver vs the packaged driver will cause issues, certainly if you do an upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04